# How to set row number value to Textboxfor on each row when add dynamically in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Good morning, I am creating a project in MVC I am just learning to use it. But my question is how to place the row number value of the table in a textbox that had a ID called "nrow" when I generate it dynamically? I share the GIF that I made so that it shows better what I mean.

[Number Row to TextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8kTv.gif)

Here's my View code

```
@model List<MvcApplication30.TB_CS_TEST>

<style>
    th {
        text-align:left;
    }
    td {
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Bulk","Bulk", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px green">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }

        <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add Product</a></div>
        <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {
                int j = 0;


                foreach (var i in Model.GroupBy(a => a.CONTACTID))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownList("DESCRIPTION", "Select Description")</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CONTACTNO)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CONTACTPERSON, new { id = "proli" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].EMAILID, new { id = "nrow" })</td>
                        <td>
                                <a href="#" id="remove" class="remove">Remove</a>                   
                        </td>                      
                   </tr>
                }
            }
         </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
          @Html.DropDownList("NAMEPLACE", "Select Place")
    }
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@* Here I will add Jquery Code for validation / dynamically add new rows / Remove rows etc *@
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function numberRows($t) {
                var c = 0;
                $t.find("tr").each(function (ind, el) {
                    $(el).find("td:eq(0)").html(++c);
                });
            }
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var last = $('#dataTable>tbody>tr:last');
                if (last.length > 0) {
                    var name = last.children().find('input,select')[0].name;
                    var index = Number(name.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')) + 1;
                    var tr = ('<tr>' + last.html().replace(/[0-9]+__/gi, index + '__') + '</tr>').replace(/\[[0-9]+\]+[.]/gi, '[' + index + '].');
                    //$('#dataTable tbody').append(tr);
                    numberRows($('#dataTable tbody').append(tr));

                }
            });
            $('#dataTable').on("change", '#DESCRIPTION', function (e) {
                {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                    $(this).closest("tr").find('#proli').val(selectedValue);
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click', '#remove', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                numberRows($('#dataTable tbody'));
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        function numberRows($t) {
            $t.find("tr").each(function (i, el) {
                $(el).find("td").eq(4).find('input').val((i+1));
            });
        }
```

i think its work for you.You can do that in c# too;

```
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            int j = 0;
            int index = 1;


            foreach (var i in Model.GroupBy(a => a.CONTACTID))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@index</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("DESCRIPTION", "Select Description")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CONTACTNO)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CONTACTPERSON, new { id = "proli" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].EMAILID, new { id = "nrow" })</td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="#" id="remove" class="remove">Remove</a>                   
                    </td>                      
               </tr>
               @{index += 1}
            }
        }
```

Edit : for input value but dont use id for more than one items use class for it.
id is uniq attr just one in the page not more.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it works but I want to copy the index number row when I add dynamically a "new product" on each TextBoxFor called "nrow".

Comment: Thank you @EmreKalafat , Your solution is so clear and only just add a .find() in numberRow functions.